# How to select the same columns of a numpy array based on indices of a second array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, filtering

I need to filter dataframes or numpy arrays based on selected columns in a previous one, i.e. filtering the same columns as those in the first array.

Here is my approach:

**Excludes zero variables (filtering, selection of columns in the first df)**

```
df_NN_70 = df_NN_70.loc[:, (df_NN_70 != df_NN_70.ix[0]).any()]
```

**Sampling (separate 70% of data to be used as train/test sets)**

```
df_NN = df_NN_70.sample(frac=0.7, replace=False, weights=None, random_state=seed, axis=None)
```

**Transforming to array as in NN with keras (it needs arrays)**

```
df_NN_array = df_NN.as_matrix(columns=None)
```

**Split data into input (X) and output (Y) variables**

```
X = df_NN_array[:, 0:df_NN_array.shape[1]-1]
Y = df_NN_array[:, 427]

print(type(df_NN_70.columns))
index_list= list(df_NN_70.columns)

index_list = index_list[0:427]
print(index_list)
```

**Filtering the same columns on a second based on the column list obtained from df_NN_x**

```
filter_columns = index_list
df_filtered = np.array(df_NN_x)[filter_columns]
new.shape
```

This filtering, however, does not work because it considers the `index_list` as the index of rows in the second array `df_NN_x`, but not the columns!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter in the second dimension of the array, e.g.:

```
df_filtered = np.array(df_NN_x).ix[:, filter_columns]
```

or:

```
df_filtered = np.array(df_NN_x)
df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered.columns[filter_columns]]
```

Note that the first version includes the last element of your filter_columns-list, the second one doesn't.

**Edit:** My answer was for a numpy array, updated it to pandas.

Comment: Thanks @Nyps. The first line code worked for me using pandas df.